# Compare 2 lists and output the similar matches

Tags: python, list

I have 2 Python lists :

```
prefixList = ["12","9"]

files = ["12-a.csv","12-b.csv","9-t.txt","8-a.txt"]
```

and want to create a new list with a list of files that start with the prefix list, so the output will be:

```
fileOutput = ["12-a.csv","12-b.csv","9-t.txt"]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: If the files always conform to that pattern, `[f for f in files if f.split('-')[0] in prefixList]` would work. If the number of files or prefixes are large, you could first covert `prefixList` into a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex` and find number and search number in `prefixList`.

```
prefixList = ["12","9"]

files = ["12-a.csv","12-b.csv","9-t.txt","8-a.txt"]

new_files = [file 
             for file in files 
             if(re.search(r'\d+', file).group(0) in prefixList)]

print(new_files)
```

Output:

```
['12-a.csv', '12-b.csv', '9-t.txt']
```